Xcode release build failing to find dependcies of dependencies
I have this huge client project where we have dependencies that look something like this:
Xcode workspace
   app target, links in A:, B:, and C:
    +-- A: Framework target (CocoaPods), depends on B:
    +-- B: Framework target (CocoaPods), depends on C:
    +-- C: SPM module

Everything compiles and runs when in debug.
But in release, the build throws up errors saying framework A: cannot resolve types from C: even though it doesn't import or use them directly. Only indirectly at most, in that B: uses them internally.
Anyone know why this isn't compiling?

Move C into CocoaPods or move A and B into SPM. Mixing dependencies through different dependency managers is bad idea
